# Pandas Compare Two String Columns to Create a Third Column

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions

I have dataframe that contains two columns of different classes `diamond, gold and silver`.

```
class_pd = pd.DataFrame({'old_class':['gold', 'gold' , 'silver'],
    'new_class':['diamond', 'silver', 'silver']})
```

I want to create a new column that shows wither the classes was `Upgraded` or `Downgraded`

**What I have tried**

I wrote the below function to set the rules

```
def status_desc(class_pd, old_class, new_class):
    if ((class_pd['old_class'] == 'gold') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'diamond') or \
       (class_pd['old_class'] == 'silver') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'diamond') or \
       (class_pd['old_class'] == 'silver') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'gold')):
        val = 'Upgrade'
    elif ((class_pd['old_class'] == 'diamond') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'gold') or \
       (class_pd['old_class'] == 'diamond') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'silver') or \
       (class_pd['old_class'] == 'gold') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'silver')):
        val = 'Downgrade'
    else:
         val = 'NA'
```

Then I tried to apply the function to my dataframe using the below method

```
class_pd['class_desc'] = class_pd.apply(lambda x: status_desc(class_pd['old_class'], class_pd['new_class']), axis=1)
```

**Error**

I get this error

> TypeError: status_desc() missing 1 required positional argument: new_class

**Desired Output**

```
class_pd = pd.DataFrame({'old_class':['gold', 'gold' , 'silver'],
    'new_class':['diamond', 'silver', 'silver'],
                        'class_desc':['Upgrade','Downgrade', 'NA']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `status_desc` takes 3 arguments: `class_pd, old_class, new_class`, but you are only passing 2 arguments `class_pd['old_class'], class_pd['new_class']`. You need to pass the first argument for `class_pd` as well. Also you're missing a few things:

- you need to return the values, not just assign them to `val`. So return "Upgrade", "Downgrade" and "NA".
- In you `.apply` you need to pass the `x` of the lambda function, if you pass `class_pd` you pass the whole dataframe. `x` contains a single row of the df, so you're looping through each row and the function looks at the `old_class` and `new_class` columns for each row for the logic.

**However** a simpler step would be to only have 1 argument (the row) and define your function like this since you're not even using `old_class, new_class` in your function:

```
def status_desc(class_pd):
    if ((class_pd['old_class'] == 'gold') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'diamond') or \
       (class_pd['old_class'] == 'silver') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'diamond') or \
       (class_pd['old_class'] == 'silver') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'gold')):
        return 'Upgrade'
    elif ((class_pd['old_class'] == 'diamond') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'gold') or \
       (class_pd['old_class'] == 'diamond') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'silver') or \
       (class_pd['old_class'] == 'gold') & (class_pd['new_class'] == 'silver')):
        return 'Downgrade'
    else:
         return 'NA'
```

Then call it using:

```
class_pd['class_desc'] = class_pd.apply(lambda x: status_desc(x), axis=1)
```

Output using this code:

```
old_class   new_class   class_desc
0   gold    diamond     Upgrade
1   gold    silver      Downgrade
2   silver  silver      NA
```

Comment: No worries, glad I could help! You can read more about this way of using `apply` and `lambda` to achieve this + other techniques to achieve the same result here: https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-create-column-based-on-condition/ @Leena

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with [`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical), seems more elegant to me and more scalable:

```
categories = ['silver', 'gold', 'diamond']
class_pd = class_pd.apply(pd.Categorical, categories=categories, ordered=True)

class_pd['class_desc'] = 'NA'

class_pd.loc[class_pd.old_class > class_pd.new_class, 'class_desc'] = 'Downgrade'
class_pd.loc[class_pd.old_class < class_pd.new_class, 'class_desc'] = 'Upgrade'
```

We tell Pandas the inherent order, and can then use comparison operators.

Another way to do the last bit (after adding categories) suggested by @jezrael with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html?highlight=select#numpy.select):

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [
    class_pd.old_class < class_pd.new_class,
    class_pd.old_class > class_pd.new_class,
    class_pd.old_class == class_pd.new_class,
]
labels = ["Upgrade", "Downgrade", "NA"]
class_pd["class_desc"] = np.select(conditions, labels)
```

Comment: Working for same solution, super!

Comment: thanks, it means a lot to hear that from you! :)

Comment: Maybe `np.select` should be alternative ;)

Comment: I was working on the same answer, but this turned out a bit nicer :) (I was struggling on getting less than, greater or equal, but setting the default as "NA" is how to do it nicely)

Comment: thanks @TomMcLean! @jezrael great idea, I will add it, unless you want to do it as your own answer

Comment: @JoshFriedlander - No, be free add to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the main logic is to provide `rank` list which will replicate the importance by position and then compare position number new and old using if else.
Code:

```
rank = ['silver', 'gold', 'diamond'] #position silver = 0, gold=1 ,dia=2
class_pd['class_desc'] = class_pd.apply(lambda x: ('Upgrade' if (rank.index(x.old_class)) < (rank.index(x.new_class)) else 'Downgrade') if x.old_class != x.new_class else 'NA',axis=1)
class_pd
```

Output:

```
    old_class   new_class   class_desc
0   gold       diamond      Upgrade
1   gold       silver       Downgrade
2   silver     silver       NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to give one more parameter which is "class_pd" to your function. Also you need to give indexes of column names. For instance instead of class_pd['old_class'] == 'gold' you need to write class_pd['old_class'][0] == 'gold'.